# How to import same package name from different npm packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { Draggable } from "react-draggable";
```

**Error**

Identifier 'Draggable' has already been declared. (3:9)

What is the correct way to import the same Component name from two different sources? Especially importing two other npm packages with the same name from various sources?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
import { Draggable as AnyName  } from "react-draggable";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_export_with_a_more_convenient_alias) for one of the imports.

```
import { Draggable as BeautifulDraggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { Draggable } from "react-draggable";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first import

```
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
```

For the second import

```
import { Draggable as PreferredAlternativeName } from "react-draggable";
```

The alternative name would be a name to call the second component.